# What are the object limits per profile for platform licenses

Tags: custom-object, force.com

What are the object limits ***per profile*** for platform licenses

Comment: Have you tried searching Salesforce online help? Were the results difficult to understand? You should have a look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit per profile. This is because a user's access can be modified by Permission Sets. You are limited to 10 or 110 custom objects *per user*, with org limits on the total number of custom objects. In other words, if you are limited to 10 objects per user, and you assign a combination of permission sets that exceeds this limit, you are in violation of your contractual agreement. Note that Salesforce does not place technical restrictions to prevent this situation from happening, but may charge you retroactively for violations of your contractual limits.